# Kitchen oven scheduler for multiple parallel dishes

Tags: gratis, android, time-management, cooking

I'm looking for a free Android app that helps with preparing several kinds of food in parallel, with the goal of getting everything ready at more roughly the same time.

For example, I might like to use a single oven to prepare the following frozen food, with instructions as provided on the packaging<sup>1</sup>:

- A pizza, which takes 11 to 13 minutes at 200°C.
- Breaded sausages, with take 7 to 8 minutes at 180°C.
- A slice of cutlet, which takes 20 minutes at 200°C.

Then, roughly the following should happen:

- The app should suggest to set the oven to 200°C.
- The app should tell me to place the cutlet in the oven.
- 7 minutes later, the app should tell me to place the pizza in the oven.
- 6 minutes later, the app should tell me to place the breaded sausages in the oven.
- 7 minutes later, the app should let me know I can check whether everything is ready.

Note that the app took some "decisions", such as assuming the maximum duration for the pizza (because it is not the only thing in the oven and thus might require slightly more heat), and the minimum duration for the breaded sausages (because 200°C is actually a bit more than what is required according to the instructions, anyway) - which is pretty much the "algorithm" I perform in my head, so why not automate it? :-)

<sup>1</sup>: Note that I do **not** expect the app to read those instructions for me. Once I have figured out where those instructions are (because for some reason, they are always on another side for each box, sometimes prominently displayed, sometimes hidden in between other text), I will happily type the relevant parts (e.g. the food name, the minimum and maximum minutes, and the recommended temperature) into form fields provided by the app.

**Bonus points for the following:**

- The app is open source.
- The app can save food items with their preparation instructions for later reuse.
- The app can handle alternative instructions such as circulating air mode vs. top/bottom heat mode, and will pick the one for which the overall deviation from oven temperatures is minimal.
- The app can handle several cooking devices at a time, e.g. not only doing the above computation for several items in a single oven, but also for several items in a single frying pan at the same time.
- The app also keeps track of certain preparatory steps such as pre-heating or thawing.
- The app can scan the product barcode from the packaging and somehow already knows the instructions that way; **but** if it has such a feature, the app must *not* be restricted to such auto-recognized products and also, auto-recognized product instructions must still be overrideable, as certain products actually always need a bit less or more time than what is stated on the packaging.

Comment: I don't think that such an app exists, because there is to my knowledge no way to get the cooking instructions in digital form, furthermore combining multiple products in the same oven always has an side-effect, which may be even oven-specific (because of size, and concrete realization of circulating air mode). Therefore my advice is to use the "app" brain 1.0 which is connected to your neck and allows you to cumulate experience what products work good together or not and how you have to modify the instructions to get a result that you like.

Comment: Are you expecting app to read arbitrary instruction from recipe text or a photo? This one is going to be quite tricky to implement (and therefore finding such app is unlikely)

Comment: @Robert: "there is to my knowledge no way to get the cooking instructions in digital form" - I don't quite understand. I expect the app to feature some kind of a button to "add a food item", which would bring up e.g. a popup where I can type the food name, the minimum and maximum minutes, and the temperature. Where's the problem?

Comment: @Robert: "combining multiple products in the same oven always has an side-effect, which may be even oven-specific" - of course. Which is why I wrote that in the end, the app should alert me to "check whether everything is ready", and explicitly pointed out the necessity for a way to adjust the instructions for some products. And, as I wrote, once there are two or three things in the oven at a time, I'll rather tend toward the upper limit for the time than the lower one, for instance. But as that is a very rough rule of thumb rather than any exact measurement, the app can do it.

Comment: @reducingactivity: "Are you expecting app to read arbitrary instruction from recipe text or a photo?" - no, not at all. I'm fine with manually typing the food name, the minimum and maximum minutes, and the recommended temperature into some form fields. I'll clarify this in the question.

Comment: You find some kitchen timers [in my app list here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/domestic_tools#group_253). As I've not used any of them, I cannot tell which fits all your requirements – but a good guess would be that [TimerDroid](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.tomatodev.timerdroid/) might come at least pretty close: FOSS, available at F-Droid, supports multiple timers. If it fits, be welcome to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) with it :)